# How to send multiple images file from express server to the client?

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, gridfs, loadimage

In my back end(build by express) I was storing user image in MongoDB using gridfs. Now for testing purpose I want to check if all the images is loaded or not in the client . By this code below, I was able to fetch one single image:

```
// http://localhost:3000/avater/avatar1 (api call)
 app.get('/avater/:filename', (req, res) => {
      if (req.params) {
        gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, files) => {
          // Error checking
          if (!files || files.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({
              responseCode: 1,
              responseMessage: 'error'
            });
          }

          var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
            filename: files.filename
          });
          // set the proper content type
          res.set('Content-Type', files.contentType);
          // Return response
          return readstream.pipe(res);
        });
      } else {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'username is not corrent' });
      }
    });
```

Now i just wanted to display all the user avatar on the browser. I dont know how to send multiple images from gridfs to the cliend. That is how i wrote the code bellow. But having errors as:

> (node:16704) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory
>   leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners()
>   to increase limit

```
//  http://localhost:3000/allavater (api url)
 app.get('/allavater', (req, res) => {
      let count = 0;
      let filesData = [];
      gfs.files.find({  }).toArray((err, files) => {
        // Error checking
        if (!files || files.length === 0) {
          return res.status(404).json({
            responseCode: 1,
            responseMessage: 'error'
          });
        }
        // Loop through all the files and fetch the necessary information
        files.forEach(file => {
          filesData[count++] = {
            filename: file.filename,
            contentType: file.contentType
          };
        });
        return filesData.map(file => {
          var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
            filename: file.filename
          });
          // set the proper content type
          res.set('Content-Type', file.contentType);
          // Return response
          return readstream.pipe(res);
        });
      });
    });
```

How can i send all the images to the cliend where browser will display all the iamges stored in the mongo? Besides is there anyway to create a link for each image so that i can display them later on in my Angular project?